# Quarkus service to use another Quarkus project service

Tags: quarkus

I would like to load one Quarkus project in my other main Quarkus project.

I tried `@ApplicationScoped` in the subproject and `@Inject` in the main project however object is not getting initialized.

it throws error `javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type`

if Initialize with new it works

Like

```
@Inject 
Foo foo
```

throws error however

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

will work but it won't initialize the quarks objects like mongoClinet .. etc.

Comment: Your approach seems correct, but you don't provide any detail at all to help diagnosing the problem. That said, I would generally recommend to extract shared classes into a standalone artifact that both Quarkus projects would depend on.

Comment: I am getting the following error javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type however if directly call with 'new' it works

Comment: Same problem as mentioned here:
[external jar is not scanned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75316077/quarkus-panache-active-record-pattern-inheritance-problem)

Comment: Yes, by adding emprty beans.xml in /src/main/resources/META-INF, it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quarkus doesn't discover beans in the dependents libraries.
I think adding of jandex-maven-plugin for your other project and package it again can help to solve th.

There is more info about that - [maven-tooling](https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling#multi-module-maven)